# ActionLink (LinkText,Action,ControlName,AreaName,RoutesValue,html attribute)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, actionlink, asp.net-core-mvc

A bottom'd like code samples
ActionLink (LinkText,Action,ControlName,AreaName,RoutesValue,html attribute)
I looked at the sites do not have all of these together
Thanks

Comment: There are many overloads for Html.ActionLink(), check out the documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink%28v=vs.118%29.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately, I searched but could not find the command to be perfect

Comment: Example ========  @Html.ActionLink("Go to contact page", "Index", "Growths/", new { id = item.GroupMeasure_ID }, null)     Not Area Name

Comment: Please tell us what the problem is...

Comment: If you want to put the area name in there, you specify that in the RouteValueDictionary, like `new { area = "Growth" }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify your area name in the Route Values parameter:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Go to contact page", "Index", "Drugs", new { area = "Growths", id = item.GroupMeasure_ID }, null))
```

Comment: Please Add Control Name in Action Thanks

Comment: Hi I Use your code    **     And does not work    **And address passed to the Webbrowers    **http://localhost:38269/Teacher/Drugs   ** No Action Name And No Id Parameters passed     -------Thanks for the replay

Comment: Main Actions     **@Html.ActionLink("Go to contact page", "Index", "Drugs", new { area = "Teacher" }, new { id = 1 }))  **Does not Work